# Android ListActivity Fatal Exception

Tags: java, android, listview, exception, listactivity

I'm getting this error whenever I'm trying to start this activity :

```
01-31 02:19:19.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1318): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prva/com.example.prva.ListView}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

ListActivity :

```
package com.example.prva;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;


public class ListView extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview);
        fillData();
        }

    private void fillData() {
        // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
        Cursor c = DatabaseManager.getAllData();
        startManagingCursor(c);

        String[] from = new String[] { DatabaseManager.TABLE_COLUMN_ONE };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };

        // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
        SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, c, from, to);
        setListAdapter(notes);
    }
    }
```

my listview xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="326dp" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I don't understand this because I have a listview which id is list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ListView id to `@android:id/list` this will fix your problem..List Activity should have the listview with the  `@android:id/list`..I hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the default `android.R.id.list`, which is under the `@android:id` name. `@+id` creates your *own* ID with name `list`.

So, instead of:

```
android:id="@+id/list"
```

Use the following:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```